# Someone inserted values in all columns of MSSQL database

Tags: sql-server

Someone has inserted values in all my database in all columns.

see this image

[image]

From the Image `red` part i want to remove from all columns

(i.e) *query should be like* :

some query with string to replace with `'LIKE%'` or any other suggestions.

(i.e) `myvalues</title>blahblah.....`

i want output to be myvalues (i.e some query to replace text in all columns of all tables from ...... and persist only myvalues to that secction)

Please see the example i want to remove red part. see the image attached.

Comment: why negative , don't have solution..researched it ?

Comment: update studentdetail set [Fathername] = replace([Fathername],'</title>',''); used this query but i want </title>%' )---something like this

Comment: that last row is very useful for the question, it should be included as part of the question. It also seems you are columns with rows and database with table. Just a few pointers

Comment: UPDATE Table2 SET Fathername = SELECT LEFT(Fathername, CHARINDEX('</title>', Fathername) - 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE studentdetail 
SET [Fathername] = 
  substring([Fathername], 0, 
    charindex('</title>', [Fathername] + '</title>'))
```

Comment: awesome, it worked..yipeeee..thanks a lot t-clausen

Answer (score 0):

Use REPLACE(), documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx to replace the string with the empty string.

The statement would be something like:

`UPDATE table SET x = REPLACE(x,'spamtext','');`

If the string you want to replace varies but always starts the same you can find its position using CHARINDEX() and use that value in LEFT() to cut it off.

Something like:

`UPDATE table SET x = LEFT(x, CHARINDEX(x, 'spamstart')+1);`

Back up your data before you experiment with these functions.

Comment: tried, actually i want statement which will delete or replace string starting with </title>....and so on.

Comment: If the string you want to replace varies but always starts the same you can find its position using CHARINDEX() and use that value in SUBSTRING() to cut it off.

Comment: there is different CHARINDEX as my column values varies as you can see the image attached

Comment: It will compute the charindex for every single row. Give it a try.

Comment: tried it it deleted all column data including my values too--other thing ?

Comment: you can check what CHARINDEX() returns by running it on your data without SUBSTRING() first.